# without find command, how we find files created between two dates

Tags: linux

I need to write shell script, there i have to copy the files which are created for every second in a directory to another place without using "find" command to fetch the file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What have you found when searching?

Comment: What do you mean by *copy the files which are created for every second in a directory* ? I didn't understand what you want to say?

Comment: do you need all the file in the directory or just some?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you have provided think you just need [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

So something like this:

```
rsync -rlvp  /path/to/dir/ /dest/dir/
```

Or if you are looking to restrict it by some naming pattern (ex only names that have the number "3" or "7" in them)

```
rsync -rlvp --include="*[37]*" --exclude="*" /path/to/dir/ /dest/dir/
```

If this is not what you are looking for please explain why and expand your question